# Magento 2.3 catalog frontend product listing sort by position

Tags: magento2, layout

I have category and i want to sort it by position in ascending order but somehow it is not working on the front end.

Following is my XML

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setDefaultDirection">
                <argument name="dir" xsi:type="string">asc</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>...
```

I also change the position in category but it is all the same

[image]

Any help would be apprciated. :)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

set above settings and run index command and clear cache.

Comment: i have followed it but still the same... :(

Comment: Problem is it is not sorted ascending. It is only sorting by descending

Comment: fetch product collection and then try 
$productcollection->setOrder('position', 'asc')->load();

Comment: can you explain it a bit.

Comment: where you are getting product collection data you can add your custom sort condition.

Comment: May be something will work for you, just put this code in your category layout update area.


<reference name="product_list"> 
   <action method="setDefaultDirection">
            <string>asc</string>
   </action>
</reference>

Comment: To change order for particular category you can do something like,

Overwrite the toolbar block form \app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Product\List\Toolbar.php

Check for the function "getCurrentDirection()"

Under this function you can put your condition with particular categoryID, if you fond that particular category set $dir to "desc" and return $dir

that all.

There might be some other way to do this. For time I found this one. This will 100% work for you.

Comment: I removed sorting toolbar from layout and it wasnt working for sorting (annoying). when i get the toolbar back it all of a sudden starts working.... Magento Team should be more flexible ....

Comment: @ibrar ahmad : ok, so you are still facing issue or solved.

Comment: it is so far solved. What i did was to not hide toolbar via XML but via css and it worked. @magentoTeam may be you need to put an option in admin category config. it will make our lives easier :)

Comment: can you share a logic?